# Read file n chars at a time with bash (without counting the newlines)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

If have a file like this:

```
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
```

and would like the output to be

```
abcab
cabca
bcabc
```

i.e. I want to read 5 characters at a time and output them on a line.

So far I have tried the following: `cat test |  while read -N 5 a; do echo -n $a; printf '\n' ; done` which produces

```
abc a
bc ab
c abc
abc
```

So what happens is that it counts the newline character.
How can I prevent this from happening?
The file I am working with is several GB large so just rewriting it into a single line is not feasible.

I know this could be done easily with python/perl/... but I would like to do it with simple unix tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `tr` to remove the new lines and then `fold`?

```
$ cat foo.txt
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
$ tr -d '\n' <foo.txt | fold -w 5
abcab
cabca
bcabc$
```

If the lack of newline on the end is a problem, just add an `echo`.

```
$ tr -d '\n' <foo.txt | fold -w 5; echo
abcab
cabca
bcabc
$
```

Comment: cool! Another option is `echo -e "abc\nabc\nabc\nabc\nabc\nabc\n" | tr -d '\n' | sed -re 's/.{5,5}/&\n/g'`.

Comment: What would be the possible side effect of replacing the `sed` with a trailing embedded `echo`? As in: `{ tr -d '\n' < foo.txt | fold -w 5; echo; }`

Comment: @PaulHodges The side effect would be to remove an unnecessary process :-) I've amended my example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is pretty sound. I'd usually carp gratuitously about  the [UUoC](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/useless-use-of-cat/), but here the structure has a point if you swap the `cat` for a `tr`.

```
tr -d '\n' < foo.txt | while read -N 5 a; do echo -n $a; printf '\n' ; done
```

Personally, I'd tweak -

```
while read -N 5 chars
do echo "$chars"
done < <( tr -d '\n' < x )
```

[Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9563318/jon)'s use of `fold` is a lot more efficient, though. Go with that, though I'd like to see that third program dropped off the chain if it's a very large dataset. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ez 's/\n//g;s/.{5}/\n/g' file
```

Remove all newlines and then insert a newline every 5 characters.

N.B. This slurps the entire file into memory.

An alternative:

```
sed ':a;s/./\n&/6;Tb;P;D;:b;N;s/\n//;ta' file
```

N.B. The newline is inserted before the 6th character i.e. a line is 5 characters wide.